# How to split a pandas column into multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I extracted a column from pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
<pre>
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
df3 = df["Numbers"].head(5)
print(df3)
</pre>

                    Numbers
0     9 12 15 31 60 2 2
1     2 9 17 36 67 18 2
2    11 33 44 59 67 8 3
3   20 24 38 56 68 18 2
4   39 41 53 55 68 19 2
Name: Numbers, dtype: object
</pre>
```

I want to split the Numbers column into individual numbers as follows and extract first 5 numbers

```
<pre>
      N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N6 N7
0      9 12 15 31 60 2 2
1      2 9 17 36 67 18 2
2     11 33 44 59 67 8 3
3    20 24 38 56 68 18 2
4    39 41 53 55 68 19 2
</pre>
```

Final output:

```
<pre>
      N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 
0      9 12 15 31 60
1      2 9 17 36 67
2     11 33 44 59 67
3    20 24 38 56 68
4    39 41 53 55 68
</pre>
```

Comment: Use `df = df.iloc[:, :5]`

Comment: I am not trying to split multiple columns from a data frame, Numbers is one column with numeric values separated by spaces

Comment: Then use `df["Numbers"].str.split(expand=True).iloc[:, :5]`

Comment: thanks the following code worked for me dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]["Numbers"]
new_dataset = pd.DataFrame(df)
new_dataset[['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'N6', 'N7']] = new_dataset.Numbers.str.split(expand = True,)
final = new_dataset.loc[:, 'N1':'N5']